# 'EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file' in Pandas when concatenating all files in a directory into single CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I'm working on a project that analyzes Covid-19 data from this entire year. I have multiple csv files in a given directory. I am trying to merge all the files' contents from each month into a single, comprehensive csv file. Here's what I got so far as shown below...Specifically, the error message that appears is 'EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file.' If I were to delete `df = pd.read_csv('./csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/' + file)` and simply run `print(file)` It lists all the correct files that I am trying to merge. However, when trying to merge all data into one I get that error message. What gives?

```
import pandas as pd
import os


df = pd.read_csv('./csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/09-04-2020.csv')

files = [file for file in os.listdir('./csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us')]

all_data = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv('./csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us/' + file)
    all_data = pd.concat([all_data, df])

all_data.head()
```

Comment: I'd add a `print(file)` above the `df = pd.read_csv(...)` line then check the filename that's printed just before the error. I get the same error reading an empty file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Folks, I have resolved this issue. Instead of sifting through files with `files = [file for file in os.listdir('./csse_covid_19_daily_reports_us')]`, I have instead used `files=[f for f in os.listdir("./") if f.endswith('.csv')]`. This filtered out some garbage files that were not .csv, thus allowing me to compile all data into a single csv.